# Create an XML from items in an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I am trying to write to an xml file while looping through an observablecollection. I then want to pass the formatted xml to my model to have it write to the xml file. Here is what I have so far:

```
       public void SaveXml(string path)
    {
        XElement xml;
        foreach (var item in Cards)
        {
            xml = new XElement("Card",
                    new XAttribute("name", item.Name),
                    new XElement("Type", item.Type),
                    new XElement("Image",
                    new XAttribute("path", item.Image)),
                    new XElement("Usage", item.Usage),
                    new XElement("Quantity", item.Quantity),
                    new XElement("Sell", item.Sell)
                    );
        }
        Game.Model.Deck decks = new Game.Model.Deck();
        //decks.SaveXml("writetest.xml", xml);
```

With this, the XML file is replaced with each new node.. how do I make it so that it adds the new items to the same xml xelement to create a list of nodes to send to my model?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define an XML root element to add all the `Card` elements to - something like this would work:

```
  public void SaveXml(string path)
  {
    XElement root = new XElement("Cards");
    foreach (var item in Cards)
    {
      var xml = new XElement("Card",
                 new XAttribute("name", item.Name),
                 new XElement("Type", item.Type),
                 new XElement("Image",
                 new XAttribute("path", item.Image)),
                 new XElement("Usage", item.Usage),
                 new XElement("Quantity", item.Quantity),
                 new XElement("Sell", item.Sell)
                );
      root.Add(xml);
    }
    root.Save(path);
    Game.Model.Deck decks = new Game.Model.Deck();
    //decks.SaveXml("writetest.xml", root);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact code I use for saving an ObservableCollection, which is updated elsewhere, to an .xml file:

```
ObservableCollection<Item> items;
items = (ObservableCollection<Item>)MainWindow.mcv.SourceCollection;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Item>));
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"items.xml");
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, items);
textWriter.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it much shorter and simpler:

```
var elements = Cards.Select(card => new XElement("Card" /* etc etc */));
var doc = new XDocument(elements);
Game.Model.Deck decks = new Game.Model.Deck();
decks.SaveXml("writetest.xml", doc);
```

Comment: Thanks guys. - I am a little stuck with actually saving my xml. Here is the code for my method:  public void SaveXml(string path, XElement xelem) { XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path); xmlDoc.CreateWriter(); xmlDoc.Root.Add(xelem); xmlDoc.Save(path); }

Comment: @Stacey: just save the XML using the `XmlElement` or `XDocument` you already have - that would be `root.Save(path);` in my solution or `decks.Save(path)` in @Jons solution (path should be a full file name i.e. `C:\test\test.xml`)

Comment: Oh i know what it is doing. It is saving it, but to the file in my debug folder and not the XML file in my project. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Stacey: you have to pass a full path to the file, i.e. not just `test.xml` but `C:\projectfolder\test.xml`

Comment: Ohhh I'm sorry I missed that part of your above message! Thanks BrokenGlass, that fixed it. :)