# ObservableCollection. Help needed

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am creating a app and I need a help with my ObservableCollection. I am creating a list that has 3 things on it. A Code, a Tag and a Link, all created in the ItemModel. Then I created in the MainModel the ObservableCollection for that:

```
public class MainModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> FeedItems { get; set; }
}
```

And I wanna add something to it, but, how do I check if something already exists if I wanna check only if the Code is the same? Because the Tag and Link is offered after the Code.
Furthermore, how do I save the data for later use, in case the app closes, etc?

Thanks,
Pedro Loures.

Answer (score 1):

try as below

```
bool found = FeedItems.Any(myCustomObject => myCustomObject.SomeProperty.Equals(valueToFind));
```

you can use FeedItems.[Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132404.aspx) method to adding new feeditems

save it as xml : [Create an XML from items in an ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284396/create-an-xml-from-items-in-an-observablecollection)

Answer (score 1):

```
ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> collection = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
bool codeExists = collection.Count(i => i.Code == "MyCode") > 0;
```

Persisting the data is something else entirely. If you don't need all that comes with a database you can leverage [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28VS.92%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should implements IEquatable on your object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx

```
public class Item : IEquatable<Item>
{
   ..code goes here..
}
```

This way you can define what is used as unique key in your observablecollection or list.

here is an example:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/csharplanguage/thread/e5d3967e-717c-414d-8c26-8a88ac9551af

good luck.

and yes, use the isolatedstorage to store information on your windows phone.